# Cheers, Best, Yours

Tags: greetings

I've recently got some e-mails from a person who was offering me a job opportunity. They used to end the message using simply "Best" followed by their name.

Is this an appropriate greeting in this situation? Could I use "Cheers" in my replies in this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Best* is short for "best wishes" or "all the best", and depending on dialect some people will find it inappropriate clipped - dropping too many words and ending up too short.

*Cheers* will be seen by some people, depending somewhat on dialect, as too casual.

It depends on dialect and audience, and somewhat on context. In my experience, *yours* is usually acceptable, but I am not experienced in all English language dialects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both "best" and "cheers" are fine to use. I personally use "best" but have seen lots of people use "cheers."

Answer (score -2):

"Best" is short for "All the best."

In a fast-paced business environment, shortening things like this commuincates efficiency.  This is OK in some contexts, and not OK in others.

HR recruiting is an appropriate context, because they want to get employees for their clients as soon as possible and typically many people are applying or looking into a given opportunity.

Comment: It's not 'efficiency' that is being communicated, rather informality and a relaxed atmosphere.